# Calling a .ps1 script in Linux Powershell from a Flask route in Python

Tags: python, powershell, flask, ubuntu-17.04

I'm trying to invoke a .ps1 script in Powershell for Linux by passing a variable and triggering it in reaction to a web call to a Flask/Python API.

All the files are in the same directory in this example - Ideally the .ps1 script and other relevant files to the action it needs to take would be in another directory, but for testing, they're all in the main directory of my venv.

If I run the following code manually, via `my_venv >>  python script.py`

```
# this is script.py
import subprocess

arg1 = 'xyz'
arg2 = 'abc'

subprocess.run(['pwsh', '.\example.ps1', arg1, arg2])
```

It will work properly. Powershell will run, and the actions in the script  `example.ps1` will execute. However, if I add the same Python code to a Flask app route so it can be triggered by an API request like so:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import subprocess
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

# example route
@app.route('/example/', methods=['GET'])
def example():

    var1 = request.args.get('var1')
    arg1 = var1
    arg2 = 'abc'

    subprocess.run(['pwsh', '.\example.ps1', arg1, arg2])

    return ('success', 200)
```

It doesn't do anything. Flask debugging gives me the error:

```
Exception: builtins.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pwsh'
```

Which makes me think it's not locating the binary for `pwsh` but I'm not clear on how to fix that in this situation. In Windows, you'd put the path the the powershell.exe executable in your command, but that's obviously not how it works here.

One note is the variable above - I've tried it without, just letting a value pass to `var1` via `GET` and then ignoring it and hardcoding `arg1` to test, makes no difference. The real code does need the variable.

Any obvious dumb thing I'm doing wrong here? This question doesn't seem to have been asked for Linux, although there are some similar Windows questions.

Comment: `but that's obviously not how it works here` why not?  Fully path `/usr/whatev/pwsh`

Comment: lol OK, I'm an idiot. After determining the path to the binary is `/usr/bin/pwsh` using `which pwsh` I just changed the section as noted and it works. I believe the binary needs to be in your `$PATH` for that to work, but additional info for those scenarios is available at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/49024/how-do-i-determine-the-path-to-a-binary-of-a-process for finding the direct path. Sorry, it's so rarely that I've had have to declare the path in linux for a command that's already in the `$PATH` that I didn't even realize it was an option in this context.

Comment: also please copy/paste to an answer if you want me to accept, thank you, TheIncorrigible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, it's usually a best-practice to fully path your executables and arguments if you're unsure of the environment variables.  You can accomplish this in your example by using

```
subprocess.run(['/usr/bin/pwsh', '.\example.ps1', arg1, arg2])
```

to fully qualify the pwsh executable path in Linux.